# App Store: Auto-renewable subscriptions as a service payment method

Tags: applications, ios-appstore

There are a number of tutorials and blogs which suggest that auto-renewable subscriptions are not generally permitted by Apple in the App Store unless the app is a newsstand app.

The problem is, they are now all a [few years old](http://www.marco.org/2013/12/02/auto-renewable-subscriptions). Has anyone had any recent experience with the App Store review process and this kind of payment methodology; does anyone know if it is likely that an app which bills for it's subscriptions this way will be accepted?

I'm aware that you can use a non-renewing subscription for this, but it's not very user friendly.

For a quick usage idea, I have an app which will permit messaging whilst a subscription is active (no, not a dating app). Please feel free to move the question if it's on the wrong site.

Comment: I know for a fact there is one dating app that uses auto-renewing iOS subscriptions, and has for at least the last couple of years. I don't know if it is the exception rather than the rule, but they've pushed enough updates that I feel like somebody at Apple would have noticed by now if it wasn't allowed.